# DotNetNuke- EVOQ: recover host/superuser credentials

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I installed DNN Evoq yesterday and while installation changed the default username (host) to my name and procvided a password (which i know that i remember :| ) after some time the session got expired and now i am not able to loginto my account. As the only user was Host itself, i am not able to access Host settings and can't configure SMTP settings (as described in this article:- http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/smtp-settings-for-hosting-and-email-providers)
and i found a very good hack to change superuser's encrypted password and password salt with the newly registered user but again the hinderence in my case is that whenever i register a new user, no new entry is added in the users table or aspnet_Membership table so this smart hack is not helping me :(

I just want to know is there anything wrong with my DNN installation or what ?
I can always install a fresh copy of the software but i want to solve this problem .. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you access the files on disk and the database?

Comment: yes i have access to both

Answer (score 2):

You can also just reset it from the database. The key is setting the `PasswordFormat` value to 0.

```
update aspnet_Membership 
set Password='password', PasswordFormat=0 
where Email = 'host@host.com'
```

After that you can login with the password `password`. Just make sure to reset your password through the administration afterwards.

Comment: This was the best solution for me - sad that passwords are stored in plaintext though.

Comment: @Malissa you might be able to get around that by changing the format back before updating the password.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do this with a bit of coding. Assuming you have version 6 you can do the following steps:

> It is possible to recover your DNN host password if you have access to
>   upload files to the site.  This can be done either via FTP or through
>   the Plesk file manager.  You should place this into a new .aspx file
>   that you upload to the DNN root directory, perhaps naming it something
>   like recoverpassword.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo uInfo = 
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetUserById(0, 1);
        if (uInfo != null)
        {
            string password = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetPassword(ref uInfo, String.Empty);
            Response.Write("Password: " + password);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("UserInfo object is null");
        }
    }
</script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Recover Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>





Now visit that page on the site with your browser. It should show you your DNN host password.
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE: YOU MUST REMOVE THIS FILE FROM YOUR SITE!  If you don't, then other people will be able to easily access your host password.**

[source: Reset DNN host password](http://knowledge.3essentials.com/web-hosting/article/376/Reset-DNN-host-password.html)

Comment: Web.config saves passwords as Hashed:
 passwordFormat="Hashed"
and if i change the same to string, the page shows an error saying : "Password format specified is invalid."

Comment: Line 220:        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="string" applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database" />